# Sending key strokes in C#

Tags: c#

Help I've been trying to simulate key strokes WIN+TAB in C# successful compilation buti don't get the desired effect and i dont know what im doing wrong here is a section of my code

```
Case "Switch Workspace":
     Log.Text += " \n Switch Workspace";
     SendKeys.Send("{HOME}{TAB}");
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows Forms Sample Application and simulates ALT + TAB successful:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SendKeysCS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");
            SendKeys.Send{"{Ctrl+Esc}"}; // Simulates Windows-Key
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the MSDN Documentation for [SendKeys.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) Method

Comment: I've done that already SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}"); sends ALT (TAB) where %== ALT

Comment: I want to send WIN in place of ALT

Comment: OK turns out what you really want is this: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ :)

Comment: Use {Ctrl+Esc}. It simulates the Windows Key

Comment: Tried that its parsing the TAB key into the search box of the start menu